# Adding/Deleting JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I manage a list of plain object that I use to build and display JPanels showing information contained in those objects. One JPanel for each object in the list.
  Every seconds that list of object is updated with a new list.  From this new list I'm checking if objects have been removed (not in the new list), or added, then update JPanels accordingly.
  At the moment what I'm doing is if at least one object has been removed or added from the list I delete all JPanels and add them all again.  If not objects have been removed or added in the list I just update information on existing JPanels.  I'm using GridBagLayout for that.
  I don't find this solution good enough and what I would like is removing/adding only JPanels corresponding to objects removed or added.
 Any suggestion on Layout to use or more optimized way of doing the work is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Can you post your a little of your code with the question please

Comment: Maybe you could use `JList` or `JTable`.

Comment: A JList could hold JPanels with painted rounded title border and shadow around it ?  Each JPanels displayed has ProgressBar, JTextField, JLabel, JButtons with custom images.

Comment: @jerome: A JList doesn't hold panels, it renders components, but yes it can display all of those things, or perhaps even better, use a JTable. Regardless, if you're still stuck, you should show more information and code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I will post code but a in a few hours.

Comment: @jerome use JTable with one column in the case that you awaiting JComponent will be editable, JList doesn't allowing that

Comment: `JTable/JList` rendering scales better. Can you estimate how many panels are expected?

Comment: About 30 or 40 JPanels.  I'll give a try with JTable, but I was worried about the rendering of my JPanels.  I'll post code if I have troubles, thank you for your suggestions.